# Can I enroll in health insurance out of enrollment period (USA) if I didn't realize I had become a US resident for tax purposes?

Tags: united-states, health-insurance

Context: US non-residents don’t have to have health insurance, and are not fined. I became a US resident alien for tax purposes in Jan 2017 (automatically triggered based on the time I’d spent in the US). I realized this (that I became a US resident alien for tax purposes in Jan ’17) in Apr 2017, while doing my taxes.

Question: Any tips on enrolling in health insurance for 2017, given that I didn’t enroll in Jan?

Comment: There's no harm in trying.

Comment: Are you wanting to enroll in a plan provided by your workplace? Your spouse? The exchange?

Comment: @Kat I'm self-employed with no employees, so I think the exchange

Answer (score 2):

This question is no longer applicable as there is no longer the individual mandate for health insurance and no federal penalty for not having insurance. Please note that some individual states have their own mandates. At this time there is no official listing of these states.

Healthcare.gov gives full details about the repeal of the mandate and the plan years that are/were subject to the penalty.

https://www.healthcare.gov/fees/fee-for-not-being-covered/

Comment: A supporting reference might be useful.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisW.Rea I have added some more information for clarity.